# ClassCastException occurs while trying to deserialize the serialized object

Tags: java, exception, serialization, deserialization

I am trying to deserialize the object in java and I am receiving this error `[ClassCastException]` constantly. The object is serialized but desrialization is not working.
I think there is no error in code anywhere but don't know why I am receiving this error. please help.

serialized object code:
User class.

```
package serialization.serialize;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable {
    String name;
    String password;
    public void hello(){
        System.out.println("Hello " + name);
    }
}
```

serialized object code:
Main class.

```
package serialization.serialize;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        User user1 = new User();
        user1.name = "harry";
        user1.password = "123abc";

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("User1.ser");
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
        out.writeObject(user1);
        out.close();
        fileOut.close();
        System.out.println("Object info saved.");
    }
}
```

Now the Deserialization code.
User class.

```
package serialization.deSerialize;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable {
        String name;
        String password;
        public void hello(){
            System.out.println("Hello " + name);
        }
}
```

Main class.

```
package serialization.deSerialize;

import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        User user1;
        FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\tgsra\\IdeaProjects\\javaBroCode\\src\\serialization\\serialize\\User1.ser");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
        user1 = (User)in.readObject();
        in.close();
        fileIn.close();
        System.out.println(user1.name);
        System.out.println(user1.password);
        user1.hello();
    }
}
```

This is the error i am getting.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: class serialization.serialize.User cannot be cast to class serialization.deSerialize.User (serialization.serialize.User and serialization.deSerialize.User are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at serialization.deSerialize.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 2 `User` classes are not the same, they are in different packages. The exception message is telling you this: `serialization.serialize.User` is a different class than `serialization.deSerialize.User`.

Using "default" binary serialization as you are, the class being deserialized into must be the exact same as the original object that was serialized. Even though your 2 `User` classes have the same structure, they are not compatible as far as serialization goes.

The simplest solution is to use the same `User` class for both serialization and deserialization. If you *must* serialize one class and deserialize into a different class, I suggest you use a different form for the serialization, such as JSON. The [Jackson library](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) makes this easy to do, and you can have different classes.

It's also possible you could [override `writeObject()` and `readObject()` methods](https://www.baeldung.com/java-serialization#3-custom-serialization-in-java) to achieve this, but I'm not certain it will work with binary serialization.

Comment: i tried using a single package, and it worked.